# Postgres - function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have a function defined within Postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.earned_media_direct(posts bigint, clicks bigint, clicks_multiplier numeric, likes bigint, likes_multiplier numeric, comments bigint, comments_multiplier numeric, reshares bigint, shares_multiplier numeric)
RETURNS numeric
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

BEGIN
    RETURN COALESCE(clicks, 0) * clicks_multiplier + 
        COALESCE(likes, 0) * likes_multiplier + 
        COALESCE(comments, 0) * comments_multiplier + 
        (COALESCE(posts, 0) + COALESCE(reshares, 0)) * shares_multiplier;
    
END;

$function$
```

Tried to use it in a sql query:

```
earned_media_direct(
            SUM(message_stat.posts_delivered),
            SUM(message_stat.clicks),
            team.earned_media_multi_clicks,
            SUM(message_stat.likes),
            team.earned_media_multi_likes,
            SUM(message_stat.comments),
            team.earned_media_multi_comments,
            SUM(message_stat.shares),
            team.earned_media_multi_shares
        ) AS media_points,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY earned_media_direct(SUM(message_stat.posts_delivered), SUM(message_stat.clicks), team.earned_media_multi_clicks, SUM(message_stat.likes), team.earned_media_multi_likes, SUM(message_stat.comments), team.earned_media_multi_comments, SUM(message_stat.shares), team.earned_media_multi_shares) DESC
        ) AS rank
```

And I get an error:

> Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function earned_media_direct(bigint, numeric, numeric, bigint, numeric, bigint, numeric, bigint, numeric) does not exist\nLINE 55:             earned_media_direct(\n                     ^\nHINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Also tried to define it like:

```
 earned_media_direct(
            SUM(message_stat.posts_delivered)::int,
            SUM(message_stat.clicks)::int,
            team.earned_media_multi_clicks::int,
            SUM(message_stat.likes)::int,
            team.earned_media_multi_likes::int,
            SUM(message_stat.comments)::int,
            team.earned_media_multi_comments::int,
            SUM(message_stat.shares)::int,
            team.earned_media_multi_shares::int
        ) AS media_points,
```

Can someone say what the problem is? First time I encounter this error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clicks` is declared as `bigint`, but you are trying to feed a `numeric` argument. Since there is no implicit type cast from `numeric` to `bigint`, the function is not considered.

Do what the error message recommends and add explicit type casts to the function call.

In addition, you have to make sure that `public` is on your `search_path` if you want to call the function without the schema name.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried with CAST(SUM(message_stat.clicks) AS bigint) and got the same error: ( ERROR:  function earned_media_direct(bigint, numeric, numeric, bigint, numeric, bigint, numeric, bigint, numeric)...) @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: You must have done something wrong, since it still searches for a function where the second argument is `numeric`.  Did you do that in *both* invocations of the function?

Comment: I missed that somehow. Not it works. Thank you! @LaurenzAlbe